# The effect of a consumer proposal on the estate of a deceased co-signer of a loan

Tags: death, estate-settlement

I have finished my consumer proposal,however, my mom co-signed a loan that was included in it. I understand the creditor can still try and get the money from my mom, however she is a pensioner and on a fixed income. This means nothing can be deducted from her estate. However, what would happen to my mom's estate? Would the creditor be able to get the remainder of the money from her estate when it goes probate?

Comment: You need to specify _where_ (country, state, maybe even county) where your mom lives and where you live, and perhaps explain a little about the _consumer proposal_ that you have finished. To whom did you submit it? What exactly is the information in it, and why does your mother's loan information appear on it?